# how to get tensor in default graph

Tags: tensorflow

I just write a model class, in its init function, I build a graph and then I want to training with the tensor in the default graph, but I just dont know how to get those tensor in that graph. The `ae` is Autoencoder class and it has some class function like `partial_fit()`. For example, I want to get `ae` and `x` in `train_test()`.

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self, param):
        # deal param
        self.param = param

        # create & build graph
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        self.init_graph = self.build_graph()

        # create session
        config = tf.ConfigProto()
        config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
        gpu_num = os.getpid() % 1 # cuda_gpu_count()
        config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = str(gpu_num)
        self.sess = tf.Session(config=config, graph=self.graph)

    def build_graph(self):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            # define the autoencoder
            x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_hidden2])
            ae = Autoencoder(n_layers=[n_inputs, n_hidden],
                             transfer_function=tf.nn.relu,
                     optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr))

            return tf.global_variables_initializer()

    def __del__(self):
        # explicitly collect resources by closing and deleting session and graph
        self.sess.close()
        del self.sess
        del self.graph
        del self.param

    # train models and return the test accuracy
    def train_test(self, train_data, train_label, test_data, test_label):
        with self.graph.as_default():

            # Initialization
            sess = self.sess
            sess.run(self.init_graph)

            temp1 = ae.partial_fit()
            temp2 = x
```

I think because I have use with `self.graph.as_default():` in `train_test` function so I can get those tensor directely, but it shows that those name is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define it as a class attribute like this:

```py
    def build_graph(self):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            # define the autoencoder
            self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_hidden2])
            self.ae = Autoencoder(
                n_layers=[n_inputs, n_hidden], transfer_function=tf.nn.relu,
                optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr))

            return tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

And then access these attributes using `self`:

```py
def train_test(self, train_data, train_label, test_data, test_label):
    with self.graph.as_default():

        # Initialization
        sess = self.sess
        sess.run(self.init_graph)

        temp1 = self.ae.partial_fit()
        temp2 = self.x
```

Alternatively, you could retrieve the tensor by using `graph.as_graph_element()`, for example:

```py
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2), name='input')

    logits = tf.layers.dense(x, 2)

input_ = graph.as_graph_element('input',
                                allow_tensor=True,
                                allow_operation=True)
# `input_` is an operation that outputs placeholder `x`
input_ = input_.outputs[0] 
print(x == input_) # True
```

Comment: the 'as_graph_element'  can only get the tensor in graph, but how about the op defined  in that graph, or how to set the name to an op and then to use it.

Comment: It allows to retrieve both tensors and ops. To set name for an op use `name` keyword argument while defining an op/tensor.

Comment: so if input is an op, that wo don't need to use 'input_.outputs[0]' to get the original op, right?

Comment: Right. Actually the `x` in my example gets the name `x.name == input:0`. So if you retrieve it using `as_graph_element('input:0')` you will get a placeholder and not the op. Note that in tensorflow ANY tensor is the output of some the underlying op, as in this case.

Comment: thanks a lot ,i got it, all tensor is from op, as its output.